# How to do verification of App Signature at Runtime in Ionic Framework based (hybrid) application?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, signature, verification, hybrid

Android apps are digitally signed. A digital signature, in this context, is a cryptographic construct that a developer applies to a piece of software to prove he/she wrote it. If an attacker has modified something in the app and re-sign it with its own signature, the app should not be able to run. The application should check the current signature of the app with
the developer’s signature at runtime.

This is first time I came across this subject & its implementation, pretty new!
I could not find any reliable resource anywhere that could specifically explain this for a hybrid app (Ionic). Any help would be appreciated :)

EDIT:
I came across this [plugin](https://github.com/iamshajeer/CordovaReadApplicationSignature) but it does not seems to work in ionic for me.